# Need help converting iterative process to recursive

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I am trying to convert the following iterative code:

```
int rows = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < rows-i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("-");
        }


        System.out.println();
    }
```

with the output:

```
---
*--
**-
***
```

to recursive code. This is for an assignment. I created the iterative code in hopes of being able to figure out how to directly convert it to recursive. Here's my effort of that:

```
public void stringY(int star, int count){
        if (star > 0){
            System.out.print("*");
            stringY(star - 1, count);
        }
}

public void stringX(int dash,int count){
    if (dash == -1) {
        return;
    }else if (dash < count){
        System.out.print("-");
        stringX(dash - 1, count);
    } else if (dash == count){
        stringX(dash - 1, count);
    }
}


public void printPattern(int n) {
    if (n == -1){
        return;
    } else {
        printPattern(n-1);
        stringY(n, n);
        stringX(n, n);
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

My issue here is that while I get the output I am looking for with regard to the "*" part of the pattern, I have absolutely no clue how to get the "-" part of the pattern. Now being that this is an assignment I don't want any solutions, but any pointers in the right direction are absolutely welcome. I should note that my two requirements are: 1) I have to complete my assignment entirely without using loops and 2) I can use as many helper methods as I need, but the main calling method (printPattern) must stay public void and must continue to only accept integers. Further clarification: The other two methods in the recursive code block are helper methods I created.

Answer (score 1):

First let m = number of '*' to print and let n = number of '-' to print

For each recursion, increment m by 1 and decrement n by 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printPattern(3);
}

public static void printPattern(int n) {
    printing(n, n);
}

//Variable size basically represent the number of columns
public static void printing(int n, int size) {
    //stop condition
    if(n == -1)
        return;

    //m is the number of * to print
    int m = size - n;
    printAsterisk(m);

    //n is the number of - to print
    printHyphen(n);

    System.out.println();

    printing(n - 1, size);
}

public static void printAsterisk(int m) {
    if(m == 0)
        return;
    System.out.print('*');
    printAsterisk(m - 1);
}

public static void printHyphen(int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return;
    System.out.print('-');
    printHyphen(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: You have used there a `for` loop for inner logic which can't be recursive for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way, they are all just loops doing some work. All you need is theoretically one recursive function that calls itself till the passed value.

```
void loop(int i, int till, Worker doThis) {
    if (i>=till) return;
    doThis.work(i);
    loop(i+1, till, doThis);
}
```

Worker is just an interface,

```
public interface Worker {
    void work(int index);
}
```

Now we need to pass the work that needs to be done. There are three loops, hence three calls to the `loop` function.

```
final int rows = 3;
// outer loop
loop(0, rows+1, new Worker() {
    public void work(int index) {
        // Stars
        loop(0, index, new Worker() {
            public void work(int index) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        });
        // Dashes
        loop(0, rows-index, new Worker() {
            public void work(int index) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        });
        System.out.println();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm curious about this. As I am still a beginner in programming, I haven't yet reached learning about interfaces. Is there a resource anyone might recommend to learn about them?

Comment: [Core Java](http://www.horstmann.com/corejava.html) by Horstmann. Get volume 1 and read the first few chapters.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by extracting then `STAR` and `DASH`,

```
private static final String DASH = "-";
private static final String STAR = "*";
```

Next, I would write a method to repeat a `String` a given number of times. Also, I would use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (here I've done it recursively)

```
private static StringBuilder repeat(StringBuilder sb, String str, int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        sb.append(str);
        repeat(sb, str, n - 1);
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Next, a private recursive method to print the pattern based on `StringBuilder`

```
private static void printPattern(StringBuilder sb, int s) {
    System.out.println(sb);
    int p = sb.indexOf(DASH, s);
    if (p > -1) {
        sb.replace(p, p + DASH.length(), STAR);
        printPattern(sb, s + STAR.length());
    }
}
```

And finally the public method

```
public static void printPattern(int n) {
    printPattern(repeat(new StringBuilder(), DASH, n), 0);
}
```