# Recursion issues

Tags: java, recursion

My code is supposed to print the output below when called with 3, but everytime I run it it just prints 2 lines of null.

```
---
*--
**-
***
```

Everytime I try to change something it gives a stack overflow error when I run it. I know how to fix this output but not recursively. We are not allowed to use any loops so that is where I am running into issues. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public void printPattern(int n) {
if(n>0){
    System.out.println(printPatternStripes(n));
    printPatternStripes(n-1);
    System.out.println(printPatternStars(n));
    printPatternStars(n+1);
}
}
  private String printPatternStars(int stars){
      if(stars==0){
        return printPatternStars(stars+1) + "*"; 


      }
      else{
    return null;
  }}

    private String printPatternStripes(int stripes){
        if(stripes!=0){
            return printPatternStripes(stripes-1)+ "_";
        }
        else{
        return null;
    }}
```

Comment: if(stars!=0) you return null and if(stripes!=0) you return null. This is causing you lots of problems.

Comment: Must be a [classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43434546/2970947).

Comment: it is supposed to start with just underscores and replace them with * one at a time per line until it hits the base case

Comment: `printPatternStripes`'s purpose in life is to return a value, not to print anything, the way you've written it.  That means that you've given it the wrong name, which is probably confusing you.  It also means that when you call `printPatternStripes(n-1);`, it does nothing useful.  The method returns a string but you don't print it or anything.

Comment: Also look at what `printPatternStars` does.  It looks like the purpose of `printPatternStars(n)` is to return a string with `n` stars.  So how do you return a string with 5 stars?  According to your code (or what your code will be once you fix a typo), you start by generating a string with 6 stars and adding another star to it.  To generate a string with 6 stars, you generate a string with 7 stars and add another star to it.  And so on.  When does it stop?  When you crash on `StackOverflow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're allowed to use helper methods, then something like this would work:

```
public void printPattern(int n) {
    printHelper(n, n);
}

public void printHelper(int n, int initialSize) {
    if(n > 0) {
        printHelper(n - 1, initialSize);
    }

    System.out.print(stringHelper("*", n));
    System.out.println(stringHelper("-", initialSize - n));
}

public String stringHelper(String string, int length) {
    if (length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    if (string.length() == length) {
        return string;
    }

    return stringHelper(string + string.charAt(0), length);
}
```

Usage:

```
printPattern(3);

>> ---
   *--
   **-
   ***
```

Comment: I can't change the parameters but I can use helper methods

Comment: @J.Doe Make sure your instructor thinks it's OK to use `Collections.nCopies`.  If they want you to use recursion to generate the substrings of stars, and the substrings of dashes, as you attempted to do in your question, they might consider using a library method like this to be cheating.  If you can't use them, you could still write your own recursive helper method that does the same thing as `String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, "*"))`.

Comment: I am not sure if it will causes issues. Is there a simpiler way to do the print statements?

Comment: @J.Doe I agree with ajb, I'll write up a recursive `String` repeater which can safely replace `Collections#nCopies`.

Comment: @J.Doe It should be good now!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @J.Doe You're welcome!  If I've solved your problem, feel free to upvote/accept the answer by clicking the green tick on the left side of the post!

Comment: just did thanks again

Answer (score -1):

One problem is that instead of `return null;`, you should `return "";` in the two else statements.

Comment: now it is just returning one solid line